# How are data channels negotiated between two peers with WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, sctp, rtcdatachannel

The WebRTC `RTCPeerConnection` interface has a [`createDataChannel`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-createdatachannel) method and an [`ondatachannel`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-ondatachannel) event handler. How do these interact? How do I create a single data channel that can be used to send/receive data between two peers?

Also, the `RTCDataChannelInit` constructor has a [`negotiated`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcdatachannelinit-negotiated) field, which by default is set to `false` and says it results in the channel being announced in-band. What happens if it's set to `true`?

Answer (score 41):

Firstly: to create **any** data channel, the peers need to exchange an SDP offer/answer that negotiates the properties of the SCTP connection used by all data channels. This doesn't happen by default; you must call `createDataChannel` before calling `createOffer` for the offer to contain this SCTP information (an "m=application" section in the SDP).

If you *don't* do this, the data channel state will be stuck forever at `connecting`.

With that out of the way, there are two ways to negotiate a data channel between two peers:

**In-band negotiation**

This is what occurs by default, if the `negotiated` field is not set to `true`. One peer calls `createDataChannel`, and the other connects to the `ondatachannel` `EventHandler`. How this works:

1. Peer A calls `createDataChannel`.
2. Normal offer/answer exchange occurs.
3. Once the SCTP connection is up, a message is sent in-band from Peer A to Peer B to tell it about the data channel's existence.
4. On Peer B, the `ondatachannel` `EventHandler` is invoked with a new data channel, created from the in-band message. It has the same properties as the data channel created by Peer A, and now these data channels can be used to send data bidirectionally.

The advantage of this approach is that data channels can be created dynamically at any time, without the application needing to do additional signaling.

**Out-of-band negotiation**

Data channels can also be negotiated out-of-band. With this approach, instead of calling `createDataChannel` on one side and listening for `ondatachannel` on the other side, the application just calls `createDataChannel` on both sides.

1. Peer A calls `createDataChannel({negotiated: true, id: 0})`
2. Peer B also calls `createDataChannel({negotiated: true, id: 0})`.
3. Normal offer/answer exchange occurs.
4. Once the SCTP connection is up, the channels will instantly be usable (`readyState` will change to `open`). They're matched up by the ID, which is the underlying SCTP stream ID.

The advantage of this approach is that, since no message needs to be sent in-band to create the data channel on Peer B, the channel is usable sooner. This also makes the application code simpler, since you don't even need to bother with `ondatachannel`.

So, for applications that only use a fixed number of data channels, **this approach is recommended**.

Note that **the ID you choose is not just an arbitrary value**. It represents an underlying 0-based SCTP stream ID. And these IDs can only go as high as the number of SCTP streams negotiated by the WebRTC implementations. So, if you use an ID that's too high, your data channel won't work.

**What about native applications?**

If you're using the [native webrtc library](https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/) instead of the JS API, it works the same way; things just have different names.

C++:

- `PeerConnectionObserver::OnDataChannel`
- `DataChannelInit::negotiated`
- `DataChannelInit::id`

Java:

- `PeerConnection.Observer.onDataChannel`
- `DataChannel.Init.negotiated`
- `DataChannel.Init.id`

Obj-C:

- `RTCPeerConnectionDelegate::didOpenDataChannel`
- `RTCDataChannelConfiguration::isNegotiated`
- `RTCDataChannelConfiguration::channelId`

Comment: Thanks it works. This steps must be included in mozilla Web API docs (mozilla)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very in-depth article about the particulars of peer-to-peer...

https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-webrtc-and-the-mechanics-of-peer-to-peer-connectivity-87cc56c1d0ab

Primary sources...

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel

The mother load of peer-to-peer projects...

https://github.com/kgryte/awesome-peer-to-peer