# WebRTC: Can I create datachannels with the same label?

Tags: webrtc

I want to make a data channel for the local peer connection and remote peer connection to connect to.

Can I run `peerConnection.createDataChannel('datachannel');` on BOTH the local and remote clients so that they both connect to the same data channel? Or does the caller (aka the client running `createOffer`) have to be the one to run this command and the answerer (aka the client running `createAnswer`) have to run `peerConnection.ondatachannel = ...` ?

Just trying to see if I can simplify it or if the caller has to be the one to create the data channel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are data channels negotiated between two peers with WebRTC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788872/how-are-data-channels-negotiated-between-two-peers-with-webrtc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createOffer()` caller should create `pc.createDataChannel('datachannel');` and `createAnswer()` receiver should just listen for `pc.ondatachannel`

See full [explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Simple_RTCDataChannel_sample) and [demo](https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/s/webrtc-simple-datachannel/)